# Two-Way Binding Across Components in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I have a Polymer app that has some nested components. I'm trying to share a property value across the components. My thought was that I could do this with data-binding. However, I have been unsuccessful in my attempt, which can be seen in this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwabBPOAvcmqsR1TOXOf?p=preview). The relevant code (I think) is here:

```
  <neon-animated-pages selected="[[selectedPageIndex]]" style="height:100%;">
    <view-1 is-enabled="{{ isEnabled }}"></view-1>
    <view-2 is-enabled="{{ isEnabled }}"></view-2>
  </neon-animated-pages>
```

Each view has a `paper-toggle-button`. If the toggle button is set in one view, I want that *same* value to appear in the other view. Yet, that is not what's happening. It's like each view is using it's own `isEnabled` value. As the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwabBPOAvcmqsR1TOXOf?p=preview) shows, I've done the following:

1. Created a property called `isEnabled` in each view ("view-1.html" and "view-2.html").
2. Created a property called `isEnabled` in the hosting component ("shell.html")
3. Used two-way binding via the `{{ }}` curly-brace syntax.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the `isEnabled` value set in one view propogating to the other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `notify` to `true` in the definition of the `isEnabled` property in you views. This is needed for two-way data-binding ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#notify)).

Answer (score 0):

First: Name your element files the way you name your elements. Change `shell` to `app-shell` in your directory.

Second: What user Maria said, just declare a `notify: true` property to each element you want to be able to databind, like this:

```
<dom-module id="view-1">
  <template>
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    <paper-toggle-button checked="{{ isEnabled }}">Is Enabled?</paper-toggle-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'view-1',
      properties: {
        isEnabled: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false,
          notify: true
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Do the same for the `view-2` property.

Here is your plunkr with working two-way data binding:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YhjE02O14YGCErXu9Vtq

Hope it helps you.